# python pandas dataframe error 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'DataFrame'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I read csv file and write a code, but this code have a error.
list_PAL is Dataframe code that have Patient Sex, and PatientAge information.

```
for i, fil in enumerate(list_PAL):
print(type(fil))
if fil.empty == True:
    fil.DataFrame({"PatientAge" : [np.nan, np.nan], "Patient Sex" : [M,F]})
elif fil.empty == False:
    if (fil[fil['Patient Sex'] == 'M'].empty == True &
        fil[fil['Patient Sex'] == 'F'].empty == False):
        fil.DataFrame({"PatientAge" : [np.nan], "Patient Sex" : ['M']})
    elif (fil[fil['Patient Sex'] == 'M'].empty == False &
          fil[fil['Patient Sex'] == 'F'].empty == True):
        fil.DataFrame({"PatientAge" : [np.nan], "Patient Sex" : ['F']})
    elif (fil[fil['Patient Sex'] == 'M'].empty == True &
          fil[fil['Patient Sex'] == 'F'].empty == True):
        fil
list_PAL[i] = fil
```

line 4 fil.DataFrame({"PatientAge" : [np.nan], "Patient Sex" : ['M']}) this code have an error

> AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'DataFrame'

Comment: You mean `fil = DataFrame({"PatientAge" : [np.nan, np.nan], "Patient Sex" : [M,F]})`?

Comment: Seems that fil is alrady a dataframe, if you want to change it you should write fil = pd.DataFrame({"PatientAge" : [np.nan, np.nan], "Patient Sex" : ['M','F']}).

Comment: @GustavoGradvohl Thank you! It works by switching to the code you said.